# winForms timer - When to initialize and dispose

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, timer, dispose

In my c# Winform application, I have one form. The form is never closed except during a reboot. The form has a tab control with three tabs (tab A, tab B, tab C). The form has two timers (timer B, timer C). Timer B pertains to functions on tab B. Timer C pertains to functions on tab C.

Currently, I initialize timer B when tab B is selected and timer C when tab C is selected using the Selected tab control event, but I am unsure if this is the proper time to initialize the timers (maybe during form initialization instead?) and I'm unsure of when best to dispose of the timer (tab deselect? never?). I plan to use the Dispose method.

What is the best way to handle this? TIA

Comment: Well, when do you actually begin to need (and stop needing) each timer? That might not be an answer, but may guide one.

Comment: You may dispose of your timer when you finish with them but this doesn't necessarily mean that they have been handled by the garbage collector - disposing will happen some point after they are last used . What is the timers for?

Comment: Answer is...it depends. It all depends on what your timers are doing and if you need them running to update the tabs that aren't currently selected. Hopefully you are only creating one timer per tab - and not one timer each time you select a tab. If it's one timer per tab then on form init is probably the best way.

Comment: There is a component wrapper for the timer so that you can plop them on your form.  This would get rid of half of your title question

Comment: @DanielLoudon: Disposal happens when something calls IDisposalble.Dispose.  Garbage Collection happens after the thing is last used.  They are related, but very different.

Comment: The timers are for counting down to an event after a button is clicked. They should only be running during the countdown to the event.